# Using sqlite3 in node.js with already installed sqlite driver

Tags: node.js, sqlite, embed, node-sqlite3

I'm currently developing for an embedded system. It already has sqlite3 pre-installed:

```
root@xxx-imx6-r1:/# sqlite3 -version
3.38.5 2022-05-06 15:25:27 78d9c993d404cdfaa7fdd2973fa1052e3da9f66215cff9c5540ebe55c407d9fe
```

How can I use this sqlite3 driver with node.js? Installing sqlite3 via NPM fails / isn't possible at all.

Comment: And what exactly has it to do with the *sqlite* tag?

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I think I got it:

```
npm install --sqlite=/usr/bin/sqlite3
```